# javascript onkeypress using regex to validate data types

Tags: javascript, regex, onkeypress

I'm trying to use the function validateDataType() on the textbox's onkeypress event.  It works on the button's onclick event just fine, but if I execute the function on the onkeypress, it does not seem to recognize the code. By using onkeypress event, I hope to alert users upfront that it's not the desired data type for a question.
I appreciate any input, thanks for help in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Challenge Questions</title>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

    /* <![CDATA[ */
    /* }]> */
    function validateDataType(answer) {

        if(answer.match(/^\d+$/)){
        alert("integer")}
        else if(answer.match(/^\d+\.\d+$/)){
        alert("float")}
        else{
        alert("string")
        }}

</script>

</head>

<body>


<div id="content-pane">



<a class="back">go back</a>
<div id="headline">Challenge Questions</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<form action="FormProcessor.html">
    <span id="subtitle">Please answer your security questions to reset your password.    </span>
    <br />
    <br />



           <input type="text" id="firstA" name='firstA' size="60" onkeypress="validateDataType(document.getElementById('firstA').value)" /></p>

           <p><input type="button" onclick="validateDataType(document.getElementById('firstA').value)" value="Reset Password" style="width:100px" /></p>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't know JS but if you use a larger change event couldn't you even modify/filter the text box string?

Comment: Are you sure the `validateDataType()` is not invoking at onkeypress event, because your code is working at my side.

Comment: it shows the same message, regardless of what I put, letter, integer, float.., doesn't it do the same to you??

Answer (score 1):

`onkeypress` event is fired before value is appended, so you should either change the event to `onkeyup` / `onchange` or delay the function

Comment: I see.. How can I delay the function?  This is an assignment from the text that specifies to use onkeypress..